Add an idx subtitle file as an additional stream to a “.ts” file?
I have a .ts file which is a satellite (DVB) recording from the TV. However, the subtitle stream in it is out of sync with the audio.
Using TSDoctor I extracted the subtitles to a .srt file.
I loaded that in to "Subtitle Edit" and was able to export it out to VobSub format.
I now want to add this as another subtitle stream to my .ts file without re-encoding it. I barely know what I am doing with FFmpeg but from reading around Super User threads I found this command and it is almost what I need:
ffmpeg -i "V808.ts" -i "V808.[2357](41001ms).idx" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s dvbsub -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng OUTPUT.ts

But it replaces the existing narrator and (out of sync) subtitle streams. How do I keep those and just add another stream?
Can someone confirm this approach does not re-encode the stream? I do to want that to happen if possible.
Update
After searching more superuser threads I have now got the command below and it does preserve all my existing streams and adds in one extra subtitle dvb stream.
ffmpeg -probesize 60M -analyzeduration 60M ^
-i "V808.ts" ^
-i "V808.[2357](41001ms).idx" ^
-map 0 -map 1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -c:s:0 copy -c:s:1 dvbsub ^
-metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 handler_name=Bad -metadata:s:s:0 title=Bad ^
-metadata:s:s:1 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 handler_name=Good -metadata:s:s:1 title=Good ^
OUTPUT.ts

I don't really understand the map stuff but it is working. I was hoping that the two subtitle streams would be labelled differently ("Good" and "Bad"), but viewed in VLC and my enigma2 set top box that is not the case.
Any other approaches to doing this are greatly appreciated.

Add -map 0:sto keep existing subtitle stream.
